# Need sendmail to pick which relay server will send the mail

Tags: sendmail

Here is my problem with sendmail

```
Oracle Linux 6.5 
sendmail-8.14.4-8.el6.x86_64
```

Need appworx user on Oracle Linux to send mail to internal / external servers
We have a barracuda t that processes our Microsoft Exchange servers.  All internal addresses need to go to 
the barracuda.
We have a external facing mail relay server that we need to send mail to external vendors.

I have done the following

1. set SMART_RELAY in sendmail.mc to the barracuda

   1.1 internal addressed mail works fine

   1.2. external vendor addresses come back from barracuda as no address found
2. set SMART_REPLAY in sendmail.mc to our external facing mail relay server

   2.1 internal addressed mail fails

   2.2 external vendor addresses works fine
3. set SMART_RELAY to both `barracuda...:external' in sendmail.mc

   3.1 internal addressed mail works fine

   3.2 external vendor addresses come back from barracuda as no address found

How do we get sendmail to determine which mail relay server to send the mail through?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `FEATURE(mailertable)` to select relay host based on recipient's domain.

[Using Mailertables](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/mailertables.html)

mailertable file:

```
# default route (SMART_HOST equivalent).
# [] are used to disable MX lookups
.   relay:[smarthost.example.net]
# route for "internal" domain
example.com   relay:[smarthost.example.com]
# route for subdomain of "internal" domain
.example.com  relay:[smarthost.example.com]
```

Comment: I tried this and it is not working unless I set the SMART_RELAY to the external mail server.  I have tried putting these different variants in mailertable    .gmail  smtp:mail.xxx.com    also tried gmail.com smtp:mai.xxx.com   also tried gmail.com  mail.xxx.com       None work

Comment: You may use mailertable and SMART_HOST together - mailertable is consulted before SMART_HOST.